# T-SQL Case statement in Where clause problem

Tags: t-sql, case, where-clause

I'm trying to get a WHERE clause working so,

- when @Status is 2 then find where the **UnitBookedDate** is between the StartDate and EndDate
- when @Status is 4 then find where the **InstallDate** is between the StartDate and EndDate
- when @Status is null then find where the **UnitBookedDate** OR the **InstallDate** is between the StartDate and EndDate

I'm thinking maybe the CASE statement won't work for what I need.

```
WHERE
TMFT.IsUnit = 1 AND
I.InstallTypeId < 3 AND
CASE
   WHEN @Status = 2 THEN I.UnitBookedDate
   WHEN @Status = 4 then TMF.InstallDate
   WHEN @Status IS NULL THEN I.UnitBookedDate --or TMF.InstallDate
END
BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it like this...

```
WHERE 
TMFT.IsUnit = 1 AND 
I.InstallTypeId < 3 AND 
(@Status = 2 AND I.UnitBookedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
OR (@Status = 4 AND TMF.InstallDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
OR @Status IS NULL AND (I.UnitBookedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate OR TMF.InstallDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

Comment: Yeah tried that but I wasn't happy with the results being returned because if Status = 2, I get 30 rows, if Status = 4, I get 200 rows and if Status is null I get 699 rows. I would expect that the sum of rows returned if Status was 2 or 4 would equal the number of rows if @Status is null. But clearly is doesn't.

Comment: Actually I've just been checking some data again and some of it is crap i.e. the dates are very old. So I don't think its a problem with the query now.